# Querying Firebase Firestore Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to build an app that functions like a dating app:

1. User A fetches All Users.
2. User A removes Users B, C, and D.
3. User A fetches All Users again - excluding Users B, C, and D.

My goal is to perform a query that does not read the User B, C, and D documents in my fetch query.

I've read into `array-contains-any`, `array-contains`, `not-in` queries, but the 10 item limit prevents me from using these as options because the "removed users list" will continue to grow.

2 workaround options I've mulled over are...

1. Performing a paginated fetch on All User documents and then filtering out on the client side?
2. Store all User IDs (A, B, C, D) on 1 document in an array field, fetch the 1 document, and then filter client side?

***Any*** guidance would be extremely appreciated either on suggestions around how I store my data or specific queries I can perform.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to achieve? I'm a bit confused by the first sentence.

Comment: @fakegirlfriends sorry for the confusion, hope my update clarifies a little more?

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. Is the user removing a relatively small number of users from view, such as a block feature? Or is this more like Tinder where the user is going to be removing a ton of users?

Comment: @fakegirlfriends like tinder

Comment: You can use rules, exclude "read" for the users that are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd approach it. The user (user-A) queries a pool of people, and each person is represented by their own document. user-A must then take an action on each person (document), and, presumably, when an action is taken that person should no longer reappear in user-A's queries. We shouldn't edit the queried documents because then every user would edit the same documents and documents have byte and write limits. And we shouldn't use arrays either for the same reasons. Instead, we should treat a collection like an array using documents as items, since collections don't have document limits.

Therefore, whenever user-A takes an action (swipe left/right) on someone else (user-X), create a new document in a subcollection under user-A that simply contains the `uid` of user-X, and perhaps a boolean like `didLike`, and perhaps a timestamp--we never know when these may come in handy.

When user-A performs another query at some point in the future, user-X is going to reappear in the results, which we now need to filter out. All we must do is check the user-A subcollection for user-X. If user-X is in this subcollection, omit the document and move on to the next person. If the UI is configured like Tinder's, where there isn't a list of people to scroll through but instead cards stacked on top of each other, this is no big deal. user-A will only be presented with one person at a time and they won't know how many we're filtering out behind the scenes. With a scrollable paginated list, however, user-A may see odd behavior like uneven pages.

This model can scale to virtual infinity.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so i guess (unfortunately) the only way to do this within the capabilities of `Firestore` is to perform 2 large collection `getDocuments` queries and filtering on the client side

Comment: @Chris You could (a) do two large queries; (b) the main query and then as you iterate through each document do a document get which you can gracefully coordinate in Swift with Dispatch Group or async/await; or (c) possibly even grabbing all of the documents in the subcollection on app launch and working with that local data set alongside the aforementioned database updates. Option c is interesting but could lead to memory problems as you scale. But this is nothing to be discouraged about. You can build a Tinder clone with Firestore with equal or greater performance.

Comment: @Chris option b is likely your best option because if the user queries the initial pool of users, you don't want to query the entire subcollection alongside it because what if the user only goes through a few people and closes the app; now you have to pay for all of the documents you fetched in the subcollection, which could be massive. The most efficient way is to query the initial pool of users with a limit of `n` (and paginate as they go) and do a single document get on each document in the query. If the document exists, omit the result; if it doesn't, display the result.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example on how to get this "You have no choice but to check if each person's uid is in this subcollection" @trndjc . I have been trying to add it to my previous query which has its own conditions but I do not know how to query over this subcollection inside my main collection. I have a bounty over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731325/firestore-firebase-need-to-combine-two-queries If I need to start using sub collections I would do it afterwards, just ignore the array I created over my main collection.

Comment: @Matias ideally, you break them up into two separate queries; make the initial query and as you loop through those queried documents, you make a single query (or document-get) on each document to see if it belongs or doesn't. You could also make two queries; the initial query for what comes in and the second query for all documents that must go out, and compare them on the client. That said, there may be a way to combine the queries into a single query, but this may require changing the way your data is architected.

Comment: @Matias You can often get very clever with NoSQL if you're properly denormalizing your data. Rick Houlihan, who works for AWS on DynamoDB, has great YouTube videos about this. Watch a few of them to see how he takes complex data sets and structures them in a NoSQL database to be able to perform complex queries in single shots.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way around.

Instead of a `removed` or `ignored` array at your current user, you have an array of `ignoredBy` or `removedBy` in which you add your current user.
And when you fetch the users from the users collection, you just have to check if the requesting user is part of the array ignoredBy. So you don’t have tons of entries to check in the array, it is always just one.

Comment: thanks for the answer sebastian. if i fetch against `ignoredBy` field from the users collection, it will read the documents the user had already "ignored". my goal is to fetch the documents the the user hasn't "ignored" (i.e. the query...whereField: ignoredBy, arrayDoesNotContain: userId).

Comment: What do you do when the array maxes out the document's byte limit? This solution won't scale.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, in best case you would have your workaround in which you have to load all users and remove the ignored once. In that case it would be cheaper to save the ignored users locally on the device.